# Do I need a wildcard SSL certificate for inclusion in the HSTS preload list?

Tags: security, google-chrome, hsts

I'd like to submit my personal site into the [Chrome HSTS preload list](https://hstspreload.appspot.com/).

The site there says:

> In order to be included on the HSTS preload list, your site must:
>
> - Have a valid certificate.
> - Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS - i.e. be HTTPS only.
> - Serve all subdomains over HTTPS.
> - Serve an HSTS header on base domain:
>
>   - Expiry must be at least eighteen weeks (10886400
>       seconds). The includeSubdomains token must be specified. The preload
>       token must be specified. If you are serving a redirect, that redirect
>       must have the HSTS header, not the page it redirects to.

Does this mean my certificate must be valid for all subdomains, or only that they are available/served over HTTPS? (I have a certificate for `sub.example.com`, but not the root.)

Can I apply to the HSTS preload list with a subdomain, like `sub.example.com`?

Answer (score 8):

## Do all subdomains need to use HTTPS?

Technically, to be included only the root domain needs to be using HTTPS, but once you get included then any sites under the root domain need to use HTTPS, otherwise connecting will fail, so practically you will want all subdomains to use HTTPS.

## Can I apply to the HSTS preload list with a subdomain, like sub.example.com?

No, if you try to test a subdomain you will get the following warning

> `example.jrtapsell.co.uk` is a subdomain. Please preload `jrtapsell.co.uk` instead. (Due to the size of the preload list and the behaviour of cookies across subdomains, we only accept automated preload list submissions of whole registered domains.)

The way this is checked is via a public suffix list, like this one: https://publicsuffix.org/list/

## Do I need to use a wildcard certificate to apply for the preload list?

No, as long as the SSL config is valid then you can apply, the certificate type does not matter.

Answer (score 4):

It is not mandatory to have a **wildcard SSL Certificate** for the inclusion in the HSTS preload list.

If you have a single domain you can use any **Domain Validated SSL** Certificate for the inclusion in the HSTS preload list rather than using Wildcard SSL Certificate.

Comment: Whilst I think this is true, do you have any reference to back it up?

Answer (score 3):

While I've not tried it personally, having read through the HSTS standard ([RFC 6797](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797)) I interpret/understand the following:

- If the parent domain is HSTS compliant then it does not have to but can enforce policy for subdomains to also be HSTS compliant by issuing the *includeSubDomains* directive in the STS HTTP header.
- If the parent domain is *not* HSTS compliant then it would not stop a sub-domain from being HSTS compliant. A subdomain should be able to work fully with HSTS provided that it issues the appropriate HTTP headers and works properly at https://subdomain.example.com/.

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to include all subdomains as SSL to get into the preload list as found here https://hstspreload.appspot.com/

1. Have a valid certificate.
2. Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS - i.e. be HTTPS only.
3. **Serve all subdomains over HTTPS.**
4. Serve an HSTS header on base domain:

   - Expiry must be at least eighteen weeks (10886400 seconds).
   - The includeSubdomains token must be specified.
   - The preload token must be specified.
   - If you are serving a redirect, that redirect must have the HSTS header, not the page it redirects to.

Does that mean you need a wildcard? Nope. You can get individual SSL certs for each subdomain. This would probably be cheapest route. You can choose wildcard, but until you have 5+ subdomains worth protecting, its not worth it financially. Either way, all the subdomains must be HTTPS mode if you want to be preloaded.

Using that thought, if you use a subdomain as a root, you would have to protect the subdomain of the subdomain in the same manner :) Or of course, backwards as well, you can't declare HSTS on a sub without protecting the TLD root.

Comment: So, to be clear, I couldn't submit https://sub.example.com if https://example.com didn't validate with SSL.

Comment: @KevinBurke That is correct brotha. Its like parent to child relationship bubbling out from TLD. Im not sure if sub.sub.example would require TLD SSL though (I've never had to HSTS a sub on a sub). I'm assuming it would since its a policy based on "root" domain authority/scope.

Comment: @KevinBurke Notes: Also make sure your HSTS cache is 180+ days to pass Quelys/PCI and that any SSL you procure is RSA2(56). If you ever decide to not preload subs, set a cache of 0 for a week or 2 to clear clients before removing preload flag.